# "The current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it" after waking up from hibernation

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, dispatcher

I have a WPF application that puts the computer into hibernation after some idle time. After it wakes up from hibernation I try to schedule another timeout. However, this results in a "The current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it" exception. The dispatcher mentioned is the dispatcher used by `Observable.Timer().ObserveOnDispatcher()`. Is there some undefined behavior with dispatchers and standby/hibernation that I should be aware of? What would cause the dispatcher to disappear?

For completeness here is the code that I use to set the idle timer and to put the computer to sleep. The `PowerProfiles.Suspend` method puts the computer into hibernation and then performs the given action when the computer wakes up.

```
private void SetSnoozeTimer(int attempt)
{                          
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTime))
      .ObserveOnDispatcher()
      .Subscribe(t =>
      {
           PowerProfiles.Suspend(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600), 
              (e) => SetSnoozeTimer(attempt + 1));                                           
      });                                  
}
```

Comment: Does `PowerProfiles.Suspend` use the same thread as it was called on to execute the wakeup action? Also, is there a documentation link you can provide to `PowerProfiles.Suspend`?

Comment: Why not just use a `DispatcherTimer`?

Comment: @sthotakura I'm an idiot. Indeed the problem was not the hibernation but that the action was performed on another thread!

Comment: @Sheridan I find the syntax for the Oberservable.Timer a bit handier, and we are using ReactiveUI in our project anyways. In the end it doesn't really matter.

Comment: FYI, don't use `Observable.Timer(...).ObserveOnDispatcher()`. It's inefficient. Do this instead: `Observable.Timer(..., DispatcherScheduler.Current)`. The idea in Rx is to tame concurrency, not to introduce it unnecessarily :-) The `Timer` operator notifies on a pooled thread by default. You're just turning around and marshaling to the UI thread! So there's a context switch for no reason. Passing in the `DispatcherScheduler` directly to `Timer` causes it to use a `DispatcherTimer`, which is slightly more efficient, as @Sheridan hinted.

Comment: @DaveSexton, I think I understand now. Will the `DispatcherTimer` execute on the current thread? I will investigate.

Comment: It executes on the `Dispatcher` thread. I.e., the UI thread.